# При нажатии на кнопку ошибка - 'QPropertyAnimation' object is not callable

Tags: python, анимация, pyqt, qpushbutton, qpropertyanimation

При нажатии на кнопку (**`TOGGLE`**) левая панель раздвигается. 
Чтобы задвинуть панель нужно нажать ещё раз на кнопку, но возникает ошибка:

> 'QPropertyAnimation' object is not callable.

Как можно от неё избавиться?
Буду очень благодарен!

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # настройки
        self.setFixedSize(700, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45)")

        # собираем сборку
        self.centralWidget_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.createPage()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget_1)


    def createPage(self):
        self.vbox_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_1.setSpacing(0)
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # сборка компонентов
        self.createTopBar()
        self.createLeftMenu()

        # датчики
         self.buttonToggle.clicked.connect(lambda: self.animation(250, True))

        self.centralWidget_1.setLayout(self.vbox_1)


    def createTopBar(self):
        
        # создание верхней части
        self.frameTop = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget_1)
        self.frameTop.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 40))
        self.frameTop.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")

        # создание области для кнопки
        self.frame_toggle = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frameTop)
        self.frame_toggle.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 40))
        self.frame_toggle.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);")

        self.hbox_1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frameTop)
        self.hbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.hbox_1.addWidget(self.frame_toggle)

        # создание кнопки
        self.buttonToggle = QtWidgets.QPushButton("TOGGLE", self.frame_toggle)

        self.vbox_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_toggle)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.buttonToggle.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttonToggle.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid")
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.buttonToggle)

        # создание области чтобы наша область кнопки оказалась на краю
        self.frame_top = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frameTop)
        self.hbox_1.addWidget(self.frame_top)

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.frameTop)


    def createLeftMenu(self):
        
        # создание области для левого меню 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget_1)
        
        self.hbox_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.hbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 500))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")

        
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)

        # создание кнопок для левого меню и добавление в бокс
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.Btn_Menu_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Menu 1", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.Btn_Menu_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.Btn_Menu_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                    "background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"
                                    "border: 0px solid;}"
                                    "QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255)}")
        
        self.Btn_Menu_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Menu 2", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.Btn_Menu_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.Btn_Menu_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                    "background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"
                                    "border: 0px solid;}"
                                    "QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255)}")

        self.Btn_Menu_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Menu 3", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.Btn_Menu_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.Btn_Menu_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                    "background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"
                                    "border: 0px solid;}"
                                    "QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255)}")

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Btn_Menu_1)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Btn_Menu_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Btn_Menu_3)


        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.hbox_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)

        self.vbox_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)

        self.Pages_Widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Pages_Widget.addWidget(self.page)

        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Pages_Widget.addWidget(self.page_2)

        self.vbox_5.addWidget(self.Pages_Widget)
        self.hbox_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.Content)


    def animation(self, maxWidth = 250, enable = True):
        if enable:

            # GET WIDTH
            width = self.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxWidth
            standard = 70

            # SET MAX WIDTH
            if width == 70:
                widthExtended = maxExtend
            else:
                widthExtended = standard

            # ANIMATION
            self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(400)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а что с предыдущим вопросом?

Comment: @S. Nick, всё решено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с именами. Пробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # настройки
        self.setFixedSize(700, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45)")

        # собираем сборку
        self.centralWidget_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.createPage()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget_1)


    def createPage(self):
        self.vbox_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_1.setSpacing(0)
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # сборка компонентов
        self.createTopBar()
        self.createLeftMenu()

        # датчики
        self.buttonToggle.clicked.connect(lambda : self.animation_func(250, True)) # animation_func

        self.centralWidget_1.setLayout(self.vbox_1)


    def createTopBar(self):
        
        # создание верхней части
        self.frameTop = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget_1)
        self.frameTop.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 40))
        self.frameTop.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")

        # создание области для кнопки
        self.frame_toggle = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frameTop)
        self.frame_toggle.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 40))
        self.frame_toggle.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);")

        self.hbox_1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frameTop)
        self.hbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.hbox_1.addWidget(self.frame_toggle)

        # создание кнопки
        self.buttonToggle = QtWidgets.QPushButton("TOGGLE", self.frame_toggle)

        self.vbox_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_toggle)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.buttonToggle.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttonToggle.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid")
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.buttonToggle)

        # создание области чтобы наша область кнопки оказалась на краю
        self.frame_top = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frameTop)
        self.hbox_1.addWidget(self.frame_top)

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.frameTop)


    def createLeftMenu(self):
        
        # создание области для левого меню 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget_1)
        
        self.hbox_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.hbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 500))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")

        
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)

        # создание кнопок для левого меню и добавление в бокс
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.Btn_Menu_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Menu 1", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.Btn_Menu_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.Btn_Menu_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                    "background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"
                                    "border: 0px solid;}"
                                    "QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255)}")
        
        self.Btn_Menu_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Menu 2", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.Btn_Menu_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.Btn_Menu_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                    "background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"
                                    "border: 0px solid;}"
                                    "QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255)}")

        self.Btn_Menu_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Menu 3", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.Btn_Menu_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.Btn_Menu_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
                                    "background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);"
                                    "border: 0px solid;}"
                                    "QPushButton:hover {background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255)}")

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Btn_Menu_1)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Btn_Menu_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Btn_Menu_3)


        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.hbox_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)

        self.vbox_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)

        self.Pages_Widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Pages_Widget.addWidget(self.page)

        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Pages_Widget.addWidget(self.page_2)

        self.vbox_5.addWidget(self.Pages_Widget)
        self.hbox_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.Content)


    def animation_func(self, maxWidth = 250, enable = True):                # animation_func
        if enable:

            # GET WIDTH
            width = self.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxWidth
            standard = 70

            # SET MAX WIDTH
            if width == 70:
                widthExtended = maxExtend
            else:
                widthExtended = standard

            # ANIMATION
            self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(400)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное! А почему ошибка была в название, то есть как оно влияло (извиняюсь сразу если выразился неправильно)?

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin потому что пока вы не сделали клик объекта  `self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")` не было. После нажатия он появился и вы получили проблему. Если мои ответы додают вам новые знания и навыки - не стесняйтесь отмечать их как полезные.

Comment: спасибо объяснили, даже не заметил